# Having difficulties downloading dependencies

Tags: maven, selenium

I am having difficulty downloading junit and Selenium dependencies in IntelliJ.
I have installed Intellij on my office laptop and to connect to the internet we have to go via proxy. I have added all the proxy details in the IDE and I am able to connect to the internet, however when I try to download junit and selenium dependencies I see the following error

Dependency ""junit:junit:4.12"" not found 
Inspects a Maven model for resolution problems. Please help

POM file details :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Temp1</groupId>
    <artifactId>Temp1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.47.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a proxy to use for some or all of your HTTP requests with Maven (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html). Have you tried this?

```
<settings>
  .
  .
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  .
  .
</settings>
```